# How to include contact form in sidebar or footer? Use Php?

Tags: sidebar, contact-form, php-include

I need to include a simple contact form in either the sidebar or footer of an existing website so it appears on every page.

This is not a WordPress site, I have seen there are several plugins for WordPress. I need a different solution. I am thinking a php include would be my best option. However, I am very new to php. Can someone out there point me in the right direction? Any advice would be much appreciated.

I have searched all day and have yet to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing something like:

```
<?php include("form.php"); ?>
```

right into the html. If you're new to php, you just need to be sure php is enabled on your server [talk to web host] if not sure.

The **form.php** file is actually just a file withe .php on the end of filename rather than .html

In the file, it will just have your html for the form. I don't know if this is the most-legit way to do it, but it's functional. [I'm learning php myself]

Comment: To check for php, you can also create a file called `phpinfo.php` and upload it into your root directory and then navigate to it in a browser, ie: `http://domain.com/phpinfo.php` and if it is enabled, you'll get a config/stats page that shows the php version, etc. The code in the php file needs only be `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If php not enabled, you should get some kind of error, or if you placed into the wrong directory it should be pretty obvious.